# In Google Sheet, how do I SumIf the product of 2 column multiplied

Tags: google-sheets

I basically want to conditionally sum all the rows that have same customer name.  But I want to multiply the item price and order count to get the total order price.  I have an equation like this:

```
=SUMIF(Orders!A$2:A$100,A2, MULTIPLY( Orders!H$2:H$100,Orders!D$2:D$100))
```

Where:

```
Orders!A$2:A$100 is the Customer Name Column
A2 is the current Customer Name Criteria
Orders!H$2:H$100 is the Order Price
Orders!D$2:D$100 is the Order Count
```

This unfortunately does not work, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Orders!A$2:A$100=A2),Orders!D$2:D$100,Orders!H$2:H$100)
```